# Google-colaboratory: No backend with GPU available

Tags: google-colaboratory

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/gpu.ipynb&scrollTo=3IEVK-KFxi5Z) it is described how to use gpu with google-colaboratory:

> Simply select "GPU" in the Accelerator drop-down in Notebook Settings (either through the Edit menu or the command palette at cmd/ctrl-shift-P).

However, when I select gpu in Notebook Settings I get a popup saying:

> Failed to assign a backend
> No backend with GPU available. Would you like to use a runtime with no accelerator?

When I run:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
    raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Of course, I get `GPU device not found`. It seems the description is incomplete. Any ideas what needs to be done?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll need to try again later when a GPU is available. The message indicates that all available GPUs are in use.

The [FAQ](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) provides additional info:

> **How may I use GPUs and why are they sometimes unavailable?**
>
> Colaboratory is intended for interactive use. Long-running background
>   computations, particularly on GPUs, may be stopped. Please do not use
>   Colaboratory for cryptocurrency mining. Doing so is unsupported and
>   may result in service unavailability. We encourage users who wish to
>   run continuous or long-running computations through Colaboratory’s UI
>   to use a [local runtime](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

There seems to be a cooldown on continuous training with GPUs. So, if you encounter the error dialog, try again later, and perhaps try to limit long-term training in subsequent sessions.

Answer (score 56):

You need to configure the Notebook with GPU device

Click Edit->notebook settings->hardware accelerator->GPU

Comment: I got Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0. Is that means GPU0, that is my Intel HD (R) Graphics Family ? How can I make it detect my 2nd GPU, that is NVIDIA?

Answer (score 8):

Add some pictures to make it clearer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My reputation is just slightly too low to comment, but here's a bit of additional info for @Bob Smith's answer re cooldown period.

> There seems to be a cooldown on continuous training with GPUs. So, if you encounter the error dialog, try again later, and perhaps try to limit long-term training in subsequent sessions.

Based on my own recent experience, I believe Colab will allocate you at most 12 hours of GPU usage, after which there is roughly an 8 hour cool-down period before you can use compute resources again. In my case, I could not connect to an instance even without a GPU. I'm not entirely sure about this next bit but I think if you run say 3 instances at once, your 12 hours are depleted 3 times as fast. I don't know after what period of time the 12 hour limit resets, but I'd guess maybe a day.

Anyway, still missing a few details but the main takeaway is that if you exceed you'll limit, you'll be locked out from connecting to an instance for 8 hours (which is a great pain if you're actively working on something).

Comment: How to check the usage limit? I mean this is just a morning time here, and I am getting usage limit exceed error for using TPU/GPU. I have only used it for an hour or 2.. and last used till previous night 12:00 AM so have comepleted more than 8 hours.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe you have at most 12 hours within a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 5):

After `Reset runtime` didn't work, I did:

`Runtime` -> `Reset all runtimes` -> `Yes`

I then got a happy:

> ```
> Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is the precise answer to your question man.
According to a post from Colab :

> overall usage limits, as well as idle timeout periods, maximum VM
> lifetime, GPU types available, and other factors, vary over time.
>
> GPUs and TPUs are sometimes prioritized for users who use Colab
> interactively rather than for long-running computations, or for users
> who have recently used less resources in Colab. As a result, users who
> use Colab for long-running computations, or users who have recently
> used more resources in Colab, are more likely to run into usage limits
> and have their access to GPUs and TPUs temporarily restricted. Users
> with high computational needs may be interested in using Colab’s UI
> with a local runtime running on their own hardware.

Answer (score -6):

Google Colab has by default tensorflow 2.0, Change it to tensorflow 1. Add the code,

`%tensorflow_version 1.x`
Use it before any keras or tensorflow code.