# Can't connect to GPU runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Has anyone found a way to get a stable access to GPU runtime?

At the moment I follow this process:

```
Runtime -> Change runtime type -> "Python 2" and "GPU" -> Save -> Runtime -> Connec to runtime...
```

And check if GPU is enabled:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

However, I get `''`, though 1 time in a 30 I was able to connect. Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: I noticed that at some point it asked to terminate all existing runtimes and when I agreed to do that it assigned a GPU runtime for me instantly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google-colaboratory: No backend with GPU available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508145/google-colaboratory-no-backend-with-gpu-available)

Answer (score 1):

The way to authoritatively know what kind of runtime you're connected is to hover over the CONNECTED button on the top-right; if the hover tooltip is suffixed "(GPU)" then you've got a GPU.

You can test for the health of the GPU HW by inspecting the output of executing `!/opt/bin/nvidia-smi` (which will only be found on a GPU runtime, by the way).

Tensorflow not being able to see the GPU while `nvidia-smi` can is usually a symptom of having done something like:
`!pip install -U tensorflow`
which gets you a TF build that doesn't know how to talk to the GPU. All colaboratory runtimes already have TF preinstalled, so you should not need to re-install it.  If you need a particular feature of TF that is not available in the pre-installed version, you can get a build that knows how to talk to the GPU with `!pip install -U tensorflow-gpu` though note that the pre-installed TF build is better optimized for the particular CPU platform used so you'll be giving up some performance, as well as using a lot more RAM.

If you've only got a reinstalled TF build as a result of `!pip install -U`'ing something else that depends on tensorflow, you can avoid this by specifying `--upgrade-strategy=only-if-needed` which should leave the pre-installed TF in place.

If you've messed up your runtime and want to wipe the slate clean, execute
`kill -9 -1` and wait 15-30s to reconnect.