# Tensorboard example not reproducing GPU profile

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorboard

When running this notebook on Colab:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras

I am not getting the same profile output for profiling: on my side no GPU device is shown.

This is what is expected:
[image]

This is what I am getting:
[image]

Comment: This same thing is happening on my local Windows 10 TF2.1.0 Cuda 10.1 environment with 2019 C++.
When I check nvidia-smi during training I see the GPU is on 80-100% but TensorBoard doesn't show the device in profile window.

Comment: This is definitely not a colab only issue, repeatable in TF2.1.0 linux w/GPU

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same problems (no GPU profiling trace, running tensorflow `r2.1.0`) It turns out that my tensorflow library hadn't been compiled with [CUPTI](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html) (despite having CUPTI installed locally).

Errors like

```
2020-01-29 14:09:01.088485: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1329] function cupti_interface_->EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
2020-01-29 14:09:01.088566: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/device_tracer.cc:88]  GpuTracer has collected 0 callback api events and 0 activity events.
```

were the smoking gun. To fix this (for my required version of tensorflow) I had to update the CUPTI library paths - (ie add)

`$ echo '/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64' >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cupti.conf`

(or wherever your CUPTI libs are installed), reload your config

`$ sudo ldconfig -v`

and then re `./configure` and rebuild tensorflow from source.

I (believe) the problem lies with the TF binary being compiled with CUPTI, and this could be because NVIDIA apt install CUPTI and don't set it up correctly - however I would love to be corrected!

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with GPUs not being available in the Colab environment. So you may have to check back later.

Referenced from this question: [Google-colaboratory: No backend with GPU available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508145/google-colaboratory-no-backend-with-gpu-available)

Comment: Tensorflow is already installed in Colab/Kaggle for GPU. At least, I am assuming that when we turn the GPU on, they switch it to the proper version of TF.

Comment: Ah I missed the Colab bit, but this seems to be a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508145/google-colaboratory-no-backend-with-gpu-available

Comment: I tried that as well. That Colab notebook already come configured to used GPU. The problem is profiling it.