# How long does Colab's Usage limit lasts?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

This message keeps popping out after I used two GPUs simultaneously for two notebooks from the same account for about half an hour (Colab wasn't running for 12 hours):
[Photo of pop-out message](https://preview.redd.it/myd7enirwn451.png?width=631&format=png&auto=webp&s=e35aefb597ddce0f7d2cca2ea050ca34510465aa)

> You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Colab.

It has been about two hours since I last used colab, but the message still pops up. It would be really great if I know for how long does this lasts. I think it could be 12 hours but would want to know from someone who has experienced this. In my case, the GPUs are available, but due to recent excess computing and running one cell for long, I have reached my usage limit for gpus. However, I want to know that after how much waiting will colab let me use its GPUs again.

Update: It has been more than 2 days and colab still doesn't allow me to use GPUs. The usage limit message still pops out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google-colaboratory: No backend with GPU available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508145/google-colaboratory-no-backend-with-gpu-available)

Comment: It has been 2 days since this happened, and colab still doesn't allow me to use GPUs. I am starting to fear that they might have permanently denied their GPU access for me.

Comment: Maybe at this point it would be a good idea to contact thei support team

Comment: @Ah_bb may I ask how much time you've been without gpu access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage limit is pretty dynamic and depends on how much/long you use colab. I was able to use the GPUs after 5 days; however, my account again reached usage limit right after 30mins of using the GPUs (google must have decreased it further for my account). The situation really became normal after months of not using colab from that account. My suggestion is to have multiple google accounts for colab, so you could use the other accounts when facing usage limits. Sorry for not replying to the comments.

Comment: Google does not allow "using multiple accounts to work around access or resource usage restrictions" - https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#limitations-and-restrictions

Answer (score 14):

GPU allocation per user is restricted to maximum 12 hours at a time. The next time you can use it will probably be after 12 hours or once a user has given up GPU ability.
You may want to check Google Colab Pro which has some advantages over the non-paid version.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yeah I think I should wait for 12 hours, but my notebook wasn't running for 12 hours, but it might have been too GPU intensive for colab free